# VAT ID doesn't show in checkout shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, vat

I'm on a 2.4 dev instance and have enabled both options:

- Stores-> Configurations->Customer->Customer Configuration->Create New
  Account Options -> Show VAT Number on Storefront ->yes
- Stores-> Configurations->Customer->Customer Configuration->Name &
  Address Options -> Show Tax/VAT Number ->required

The VAT number input shows on Account creation page but not in checkout page in Shipping Address. Can anyone help me?
Thanks